# how to get $\theta$ and $\phi$ in these two equations

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to solve the below equations but I'm not really sure how to get $\theta$ and $\phi$ . 
\begin{align*}
&a \sin \theta = h \\
&b \cos\phi \cos\theta = r
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a\sin(\theta) = h \\ \implies \sin(\theta) = \frac{h}{a} \\ \implies \theta = \arcsin\left( \frac{h}{a} \right)$$ You can use a similar strategy to solve for $\phi$, with the difference that you can plug in  $\theta = \arcsin\left( \frac{h}{a} \right)$

Answer (score 2):

With

$$a \sin \theta =h,$$

you get:

$$\cos \theta = \sqrt{1-\dfrac{h^2}{a^2}},$$

and:

$$\cos \phi= \dfrac{r}{b \cos\theta}=\dfrac{ba}{r\sqrt{a^2-h^2}}.$$